# Wrap new registered Wordpress Widget in a HTML Section

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to create a one-page wordpress website, where the navigation/menu points to different sections of the website. I would like to wrap my new Contact Form Widget in a section where the menu item "Contact" could point to. As seen in the code, I already have a 'before' div around the widget of "div class="contact-form-widget-wrapper". I can technically turn that into a section, however I would like to have more than one widget per section. Would anybody be able to help on how to wrap the widget/s in a section?

I'm using the Genesis Child Theme, which I'm trying to customize.

```
     /* Contact Form Widget***************/
function contact_form_widget() {
    register_sidebar( array(          
        'name' => __( 'Contact Form', 'genesis' ),
        'id' => 'contactwidget',
        'description' => __( 'ContactForm', 'genesis' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="wrap contact-form-widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
    ) );
 }
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'contact_form_widget' );

//* Add the Contact Form Widget in place
function contact_form_widget_visible() {
    genesis_widget_area ('contactwidget', array(
        'before' => '<div class="contact-form-widget-wrapper">',
        'after' => '</div>',));
    }
add_action( 'genesis_before_footer', 'contact_form_widget_visible' );
```

Comment: Why not do it in the template itself?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Wordpress, what do you mean by, "Why not do it in the template itself?"